# ffmpeg - mapping an audio file with 2 channels to a video file?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video file and an audio file (that contains 2 channels) and i want to map the video to stream 0 of the resulting file and the audio file to the next stream/s.

Since the audio file has 2 channels, would i have to map it to 2 separate streams? (1 and 2 of the resulting file)
Or just one stream?

Finally, how should i go about doing that?
I've only tried mapping with video files so i'm not sure how to do it with audio ones.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Channels are conjoint tracks within a single stream, so a stereo audio WAV has one stream which contains two channels. If this is what you have, use

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio -map 0:v -map 1:a output
```

If they are distinct streams, then the above command will still map all the streams, but for explicit specification, use

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio -map 0:v -map 1:a:0 -map 1:a:1 output
```

Comment: Okay i'll try it thanks!
For the first command - what if the video file itself also has an audio stream but i don't want to use it? would that change the command or no?

Comment: No, the given commands ignore any audio in the video file.